# Apostrophe CMS & Rich Text

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am trying to get a paragraph tag with a class to be generated by the Rich Text widget and nothing I have tried seems to work.  There is a lot of half solutions out there, but none of the documentation provides a working complete solution.

Here is what I want: I would like to have a menu option in the rich text editor that is "Highlighted Text" and uses the 'p' tag with the class 'highlighted-text' `<p class='highlighted-text'>...</p>`.

What I have:

I have an `lib\modules\apostrophe-rich-text-widgets\index.js` file in my project that contains:

```
module.exports = {
    sanitizeHtml: {
        //allowedTags: [ 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'blockquote', 'p', 'a', 'ul', 'ol',
        //  'li', 'b', 'i', 'strong', 'em', 'strike', 'code', 'hr', 'br', 'div',
        //  'table', 'thead', 'caption', 'tbody', 'tr', 'th', 'td', 'pre',
        //  'sup', 'sub'
        //],
        //allowedClasses: {
        //  'p': ['highlighted-text']
        //},
        //allowedAttributes: {
        //  '*': ['style', 'class'],
        //  a: [ 'href', 'name', 'target' ],
        //  // We don't currently allow img itself by default, but this
        //  // would make sense if we did
        //  img: [ 'src' ]
        //},
        allowedTags: false,
        allowedAttributes: false,
        allowedClasses: false,
        // Lots of these won't come up by default because we don't allow them
        selfClosing: [ 'img', 'br', 'hr', 'area', 'base', 'basefont',
            'input', 'link', 'meta' ],
        // URL schemes we permit
        allowedSchemes: [ 'http', 'https', 'ftp', 'mailto' ],
        allowedSchemesByTag: {}
    }
}
```

Note that I have tried both specifically allowing the class for the paragraph tag, and I have also tried turning off sanitizing as per the instructions here: https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html

In my template I have the following code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 3rem">
    {{ apos.area(data.page, "body", {
        widgets: {
            'apostrophe-images': {size: 'one-half'},
            'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                toolbar: ['Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor', 'Table', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', 'Split'],
                styles: [
                    {name: 'Paragraph', element: 'p'},
                    {name: 'Heading 2', element: 'h2'},
                    {name: 'Heading 3', element: 'h3'},
                    {name: 'Heading 4', element: 'h4'},
                    {name: 'Heading 5', element: 'h5'},
                    {name: 'Highlighted-Text', element: 'p', 'class': 'highlighted-text'}
                ]
            },
            'apostrophe-files': {},
            'two-column': {}
        }
    }) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have also tried `{name: 'Highlighted-Text', element: 'p', attributes: [{'class': 'highlighted-text'}]}` and `{name: 'Highlighted-Text', element: 'p', attributes: {'class': 'highlighted-text'}}` since these are also formats I have seen in the docs floating around the web.

So far I either get errors on the server, or I get plain paragraph formatting.  I am sure I have not yet managed to try all possible permutations of the possible variations of these settings since that is near infinite.

I propose that one simple working example be added to the official apostrophe documentation that shows this in action, including all pieces of code that must be added or changed from a default apostrophe cms project.  I am guessing this is a very common requirement for users.

Comment: The documentation has been recently updated with clearer information about this. See https://docs.apostrophecms.org/howtos/ckeditor.html. If you have specific suggestions for the docs, please create an issue in the repo: https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-documentation/issues. We'll soon be working on improving a lot there.

Answer (score 0):

The first step, which I originally left out (see UPDATE), is that your template code is not setting the class correctly. In the template `styles` option, the class should be added as `attributes: { class: 'highlighted-text' }`, not simply `class: 'highlighted-text'`. So the `apostrophe-rich-text` widget configuration in the template would look like:

```
'apostrophe-rich-text': {
    toolbar: ['Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor', 'Table', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', 'Split'],
    styles: [
        {name: 'Paragraph', element: 'p'},
        {name: 'Heading 2', element: 'h2'},
        {name: 'Heading 3', element: 'h3'},
        {name: 'Heading 4', element: 'h4'},
        {name: 'Heading 5', element: 'h5'},
        {
            name: 'Highlighted-Text',
            element: 'p',
            attributes: { class: 'highlighted-text' }
        }
    ]
},
```

If you specifically want to allow the `highlighted-text` class on paragraphs, you should be able to simply use this for your project-level config in `lib/modules/apostrophe-rich-text-widgets/index.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    sanitizeHtml: {
        allowedClasses: {
         'p': ['highlighted-text']
        }
    }
}
```

`false` may work for `allowedClasses` to allow any, but I'm not sure about that. There is another documented method for allowing any class with `sanitize-html`, however.

Most of what you include are the sanitize-html defaults. You only need to include those defaults when you are adding to, or replacing, specific configuration properties. For example, if you want to add new tags to `allowedTags` you need to include the defaults if you don't want to lose them, but if you aren't changing any `allowedAttributes` you can leave that out in your project code.

The docs for this have been lacking, but I recently updated them to provide more information about this: https://docs.apostrophecms.org/howtos/ckeditor.html#changing-the-allowed-html-tags-in-rich-text

UPDATE: I removed my comment about the `false` settings since the OP explained their reasoning in comments. I also added the template code suggestion that I originally left out.

Comment: I allowed the false values in the sanitize block because the documentation for this listed that as a way to disable sanitizing entirely.  I got this from the documentation here: https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html (look at the question "What if I want to allow all tags or all attribute?".  My goal was to remove sensitization as a source of the error.

Comment: I have used your exact code above and I still have the same problem.  What I am seeing is that the paragraph option and highlighted-text option are both selected in the drop down (in ApostropheCMS editor) when I select either of them.  What that suggests is that CKEditor sees both paragraph and highlighted-text as identical.

Comment: Perhaps I am defining the style incorrectly in my template.  I have tried several variations based on documentation found with ApostropheCMS and CKEditor, but have not figured out the magic format.

Comment: I have posted three photos showing the code files in question, pathing, and the web site.  They should be accessible via this [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/46n5ksfb1qop6uc/AAB04tH0fmr76IsVnPc7BUH_a?dl=0).

Comment: If I try to follow [CKEditor's method of defining a class](https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles): `{ name : 'CSS Style', element : 'span', attributes : { 'class' : 'my_style' } },`, then my template looks like this: `{name: 'highlighted', element: 'div', attributes: {'class': 'highlighted'}}`.  I get a Template render error: parseAggregate: expected comma after expression when the page is refreshed.

Comment: I gave your updated documentation another look and I see that you have the same syntax for the attributes in your docs now that CKEditor has.  That syntax is causing an error however, so it is not usable.  Thank you for the updated docs by the way.

Comment: I missed a template code error in your OP. Please see my updated answer.